# Is there a way I can stop script in my browser if a variable is undefined?

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript method that is giving me this error:

```
Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
```

I have been trying to debug this but without much luck. Is there a way that just before here I can check the value of the variable and if it is not defined then pause the browser so I can go to the console and check other variables.

Here is the code involved:

```
this.getFilteredTestStatusActions = function (screen, roleName) {
        var self = _this;
        var filtered = self.userTestStatusActions.filter(function (val) {
```

My problem is that self.userTestStatusActions is not defined. I want to pause the browser at this point if it is not defined so I can "look around" at other variables.

Comment: please share some more code

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: The browser should give you the line of code involved.

Comment: Chrome with developer tools browser console open.

Comment: The browser gives me the line of code but stops everything and I cannot debug / check the values of other variables.

Comment: Sounds like you may already be doing so, but using a [breakpoint](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging#breakpoints) is going to be the most effective way to do this in Chrome. If you cannot check the values of other variables, that may be an indication that there is a deeper problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you can check whether a variable is `undefined` in javascript by doing this:

```
if(self.userTestStatusActions === undefined){
  // self.userTestStatusActionshas not been defined
}
```

You can force a javascript debugger using the `debugger;` keyword.

```js
function testUndefined(myVariable){
  if(myVariable === undefined){
    debugger;
  }
}

testUndefined()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a try catch block

```
try{

  var filtered = self.userTestStatusActions.filter(function (val) {...}

}
catch(e){

  console.log(e);

}
```

or use `typeof`

```
if( typeof (self.userTestStatusActions) === "undefined"){
 ...
}
```

And attach a break point just above one of those lines.